# Python: I/O file If loop not working. CSV Cell value not comparing

Tags: python, io

''' PROBLEM STATEMENT: If condition is not working  '''

''' New to Python. Excuse for basic queries'''

'':CSV File Contains Data: "XYZ", 12345, 1000 Tagged to account_holder_name', 'account_number', 'account_balance' respectively'''

'''Current output: if condition is not working.
Expected output: want to compare csv file account_number with 12345 and print account_balance '''

```
with open('file_name.csv','r') as csv_file:
    columnnames = ['account_holder_name', 'account_number', 'account_balance']
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,fieldnames = columnnames)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    if header != None:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(csv_file)]
        print(data[0][0])
        print(data[0][1])
        print(data[0][2])
        if data[0][1] == 12345:
            print(data[0][2])
            print("Good you accessed the balance")
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Please provide your current output and also the expected output.

Comment: ``if`` is not a loop, ``for`` and ``while`` are. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Note that ``next(csv_reader)`` will never return ``None``. It will return either a ``dict`` or fail with ``StopIteration``.